# Using RAMDirectory In Lucene.net causes FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lucene.net

I have an index manager class that writes documents to my index.  When I pass it a RAMDirectory to create an IndexWriter with I'm getting a FileNotFoundException on file segments.gen

Here's my class:

```
public class IndexManager
{
    private readonly IIndexPersistable _indexPersister;

    public IndexManager(IIndexPersistable indexPersister)
    {
        _indexPersister = indexPersister;
    }

    public Directory Directory
    {
        get { return _indexPersister.Directory; }
    }

    internal void WriteDocumentsToIndex(
        IEnumerable<Document> documents, 
        bool recreateIndex)
    {
        using(var writer = 
            new IndexWriter(
                Directory, 
                new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_30), 
                recreateIndex,
                IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
        {
            foreach (Document document in documents)
            {
                writer.AddDocument(document);
            }

            writer.Optimize();
        }
    }
}


public class InMemoryPersister : IIndexPersistable
{
    private readonly Directory _directory;

    public InMemoryPersister()
    {
        _directory = new RAMDirectory();
    }

    public Directory Directory
    {
        get { return _directory; }
    }
}
```

Here's the unit test method:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        using (var manager = new IndexManager(new InMemoryPersister()))
        {
            IList<Recipe> recipes = Repositories.RecipeRepo.GetAllRecipes().ToList();
            IEnumerable<Document> documents = recipes.Select(RecipeIndexer.IndexRecipe);
            manager.WriteDocumentsToIndex(documents, true);
        }
    }
```

I've tried a few different permutations but in this solution I always get a FileNotFoundException.  I have another very similar implementation in a test solution which has worked fine.  I've also modified this solution a few times to simply declare a new RAMDirectory when I'm creating a new IndexWriter and that also fails.

An help/suggestions are very appreciated.  Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Which version of Lucene.Net do you use? Do you get the same error when you pass FSDirectory?

Comment: 3.0.3 and no.  My FSDirectory implementation works just fine when I run the application.  I should add this code runs under MS test and not with the w3wp that the website runs under.

Comment: Just a wild stab because I came across this when searching my own problem, but are you just seeing the exception when debugging and stopping it?  I get a FileNotFoundException sometimes when I have 'break on exception thrown' checked and am debuggging but I think it is caught and handled by Lucene and when I let the app continue it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: No, it will bubble up as another exception if it runs it's course, but the base exception is the FileNotFound exception.

Comment: Jason Goemaat your stab turned out to be correct.  I was catching all first chance exceptions in Visual Studio.  Once I turned that off the RAMDirectory started working properly.  Good call.  If you submit an answer I'll see if I can give you the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had enabled break on CLR Exceptions.  Lucene was throwing exceptions and would handle them but I was interrupting that process.  Once I disabled the CLR Exception break my tests worked successfully using a RAMDirectory.

Answer (score 1):

A Index Writer will throw a FileNotFound Exception if the create argument is false and Directory does not yet contain an Index. And with a RAMDirectory, the first time an IndexWriter is opened on it, it will not have an index. If you want it to create the index then, you can pass `IndexReader.IndexExists(Directory) || recreate` to the constructor instead of just `recreate`.

Another option would be to use one of the IndexWriter constructors that doesn't have a create argument, which will create the index if it doesn't exist, or open the existing one if it does.

Comment: I updated my sample code with my unit test method.  In this case I'm telling it to create a new index by passing true to the WriteDocumentsToIndex method.  Which still throws the exception.  Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't appear to effect the state of the "files" the memory index is complaining it cannot find.